# Determine the number of elements $a$ satisfying $\mathbb{F}_{5^4} =\mathbb{F}_5(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

**Problem:**

> Consider the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$.
>   **(a)** Determine the number of elements $a$ satisfying $\mathbb{F}_{5^4} = \mathbb{F}_5(a)$.
>   **(b)** Determine the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $4$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

My attempt for part **(a)** was to consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^{5^4}-  x$, because I know it splits in $\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$ and the extension is Galois. So if $a$ is a root of $f(x)$ and $a$ is not in $\mathbb{F}_5$, then $a$ is in $\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$. But I don't see a way to access these elements in a way that allows them to be counted.

For part **(b)** I know that the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is given by the general formula 
$$\psi(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) p^{n/d}.$$
So 
\begin{align} \psi(4) &= \frac{1}{4}[\mu(1)5^4 + \mu(2)5^2 + \mu(4)5^1 ] \\
&= \frac{1}{4}[ 5^4 - 5^2] \\
&= 150 
\end{align}
However, using the formula wasn't very enlightening. Is there a nice way to use part (a) to make a counting argument?

Comment: +1 for sharing your thoughts. In part (a) you seem to have forgotten about the intermediate field $\Bbb{F}_{5^2}$. But, it happens to be the only intermediate field. Is it clear to you that $\Bbb{F}_5(a)=\Bbb{F}_{5^4}$ if and only if $a\notin\Bbb{F}_{5^2}$? How many choices of $a$ does this rule out?

Comment: If $a\notin\Bbb F_5$, then $a$ could generate $\Bbb F_{25}$ rather than $\Bbb F_{625}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) $\mathbb{F}_5(a)=\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$ iff $\mathbb{F}_5(a)$ is not a strictly smaller subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$. Because $4$ has only two proper divisors ($2$ and $1$), there are only two such subfields: $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{5^1} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{5^2}$.
Therefore, $\mathbb{F}_5(a)=\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$ iff $a \in \mathbb{F}_{5^4} \setminus \mathbb{F}_{5^2}$.

(b) $\mathbb{F}_5(a)=\mathbb{F}_{5^4}$ iff $a$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $4$ irreducible  over $\mathbb F_5$.
There are $600=625-25$ possibilities for $a$. They can be grouped in groups of $4$, the roots of the same irreducible polynomial of degree $4$. Therefore, there are $600/4=150$ such polynomials.